# Bootstrap v5, get three images slightly overlap

Tags: html, image, layout, bootstrap-5

I'm new to posting on StackOverflow.  I have been trying to create a website where the landing page shows 3 images, clipped at a slight angle.  My issue is I can't get rid of the white space between them or get them to grow and shrink with the webpage correctly.  I'm on week 2 of trying to figure it out so I'm turning to StackOverflow.  I believe I mostly figured it in in vanilla code but can't seem to do it on Boostrap.  I seem to have a lot of trouble with getting elements to interact they way I want.  I've taken a course and watched Youtube videos.  But layouts are still difficult for me.

Vanilla code attempt
https://codepen.io/SeanFrameWork/pen/KKyGYyd

Bootstrap attempt
https://www.codeply.com/p/zP01n9HorV

```
<div class="container mh-100 mw-100 img-wrapper">
    <div class="row mw-100">
        <div class="col p-0" style="outline: dotted;">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/500/800/people" class="img-fluid m-0 p-0 col makeup-left" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
        <div class="col p-0" style="outline: dotted;">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/500/800/animals" class="img-fluid m-0 p-0 col makeup-center" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
        <div class="col p-0" style="outline: dotted;">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/500/800/people" class="img-fluid m-0 p-0 col makeup-right" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
/* build your own custom Bootstrap theme:
   https://themestr.app
*/
.img-wrapper {
  outline: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.makeup-left {
    position: absolute;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.makeup-center {
    position: absolute;
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.makeup-right {
    position: absolute;
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

Comment: Bit confused as to the version of Bootstrap that you're using. v3 in the title. v4/5 class types in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your title says Bootstrap 3 but is that what you're definitely using? This answer assumes so.

So, remove the `.img-wrapper` and `.makeup-*` CSS as it might get in the way. You may have to add more of your own styling again later to make things perfect.

In Bootstrap you can very easily get the columns resizing with your screen width. You have 3 divs and each of them has an image inside like this.....

```
<div class="col p-0" style="outline: dotted;">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/500/800/people" 
    class="img-fluid m-0 p-0 col makeup-left" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

Instead of using `col` use `col-sm-12 col-md-4`. This will stack your images into 1 column in mobile view and have 3 equally sized columns side by side and all responsive on medium screens and above. You could instead just use `col-4` to have 3 columns on all screens but these columns might not be very readable on smaller screens.

Also, You have used `img-fluid` to get the responsiveness and resizing but this class is for Bootstrap 4 and above. For Bootstrap 3 change it to `img-responsive`.

Just one othert thing, remove `col` from your image classes as we have asked the images to be `img-responsive` inside their parent div/col.

It ends up like this....

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 p-0" style="outline: dotted;">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/500/800/people" 
    class="img-responsive m-0 p-0 makeup-left" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh sorry about that.  I meant I'm using Bootstrap and I have 3 images I want to slightly overlap.  They are clipped at an angle and that is the reason I want them to line up.  Also thank you so much for taking the time to help me.  I'm trying these changes now.